# Do living beings really learn from punishments?

Tags: karma, sin, samskara, punishment, destiny

We know from the law of karma that good deeds lead to rewards and bad deeds lead to punishments and the loka where you will reincarnate to experience the effects of your actions will depend on the gravity of your merits or sins. But when it comes to sins, will the jivas learn through pain that those actions are not to be repeated? It seems counterintuitive too me, as a lot of people who have been physically and psychologically traumatised and abused (born in families where this was meant to happen as per their karmas, for instance) suffer so much that they barely cope without even knowing the reason of their apparently dark destiny. And when one suffers that much, the instinct is to multiplicate that energy. You pass it to other generations causing suffering in other living beings as well. This is because you haven't received love and haven't been brought up in a compassionate, supportive and kind home, so you don't know what this truly means to experience, rather than reading about these concepts in books/scriptures or hearing them from others. So, how can suffering not cause more suffering in the world (by perpetuating the bad vibes) and even hate towards God (that created the law of karma) especially when one is prone to commit the same mistakes due to the samskaras of their mind?

Comment: What exactly is suffering acc to Sanatana Dharma(defn), is pain the same as suffering?Is it different then how? Who is suffering(is it the body/mind/smthing else)?Why are we suffering?Did God create us to suffer?I think answers to these Qns are imp prior to understanding the ans to your Qn.I kindly req you to first read up ans for these Qns already asked on this website, think deeply about them for atleast a day or two,come back rephrase your Qn,post about your research, then ask **specific** doubts, as the ans may get too long if you are unaware of the basics. Happy reading :)